# Mysql SELECT query on name ignoring the first word if it is "the", "a", "an" etc

Tags: mysql, regex, select

I've been trying (without success) to construct a MYSQL query which will select a group of records with a "title" field starting with a single alphabetical character but ignoring the first word if it's "The", "An" or "A".  I've found plenty of examples that do this for the ORDER BY part of the query, but it's the initial WHERE part that I need to do it for, as the order is irrelevant if the correct records haven't been found.  Using

```
WHERE title LIKE "R%"
```

will just give me titles that have this as the very first letter (e.g. "Robin Hood") but won't match "The Red House".  I think I need some kind of REGEX, but I can't seem to get it to work.

So for example, given the following movie titles,

*Road House*

*The Return of the King*

*Mamma Mia*

*Argo*

*Titanic*

*A River Runs Through it*

Selecting movie titles that start with "R" would return the following:

*The Return of the King*

*A River Runs Through it*

*Roadhouse*

(other fields omitted)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to programmatically expand the query to something like

```
SELECT
...
WHERE
  title LIKE 'R%'
  OR title LIKE 'The R%'
  OR title LIKE 'A R%'
  OR title LIKE 'An R%'
  ...
```

This should perform better than a REGEX, as it will be able to use an index, which a REGEX never will.

BTW: The canonical way to do this, is to store the article in a seperate field.

Answer (score 2):

This regex should suit your needs:

```sql
WHERE title REGEXP '^(The |An? )?R.*$'
```

But as @EugenRieck noticed, since you probably use an index on the `title` column, you should better use the `WHERE... OR...` clauses.

Comment: Ahh, so REGEXs in MySQL come with a high overhead? Edit: Sorry, I get it now - the index makes the difference

Answer (score 1):

To add to the above suggestions (both of which I agree with), for the sort you would probably need to use a CASE to dervive a field for the ORDER BY clause.

```
SELECT somefield, 
CASE 
WHEN title LIKE 'R%' THEN title
WHEN title LIKE 'The R%' THEN SUBSTRING(title FROM 5)
WHEN title LIKE 'A R%' THEN SUBSTRING(title FROM 3)
WHEN title LIKE 'An R%' THEN SUBSTRING(title FROM 4)
ELSE title
END AS SortTitle
FROM sometable
ORDER BY SortTitle
```

Comment: Thanks - that looks like the kind of thing I need.  I want to do the ORDER BY on strings with the same ignored first word when applicable, so I think this does the job.

Comment: You should add the `WHERE ... OR ... OR ...` clause from my answer, if you want to use an index. The `CASE` itself is perfectly fine ... +1